# How to restrict access to subdirs in Nginx

Tags: at

My question is very simple, but I can't find simple answer on this forum or Google...

How to restrict access to all subdirs in Nginx ? I can only restrict access to the exact path:

```
location /wiki/data  {
    deny all;
}
```

This is ok for the data folder, but not for the subdirs of data...
Could you help me ?

Comment: The pathname parameter in a [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) is a prefix string that should match should match **everything that starts with that path, so  for instance `/wiki/data/file.dat`  and  `/wiki/data/sub/dir/` should be matched and blocked.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search for wild card nginx location will give you the answer to this. Use a ~ or ~* to indicate a case sensitive or insenstive match respectively then give the regular expression. In your case.

`location ~ /wiki/data/*`

should work although I haven't tested it.

Comment: Sorry for the big latency, I just noticed your answer ...
Thank you Catherine, that's work!